# The mapreduce code here produces an empty output file. The code and the input is given below

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

The mapreduce code here produces an empty output file. The code and the    input is given below.

```
package temperature;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.KeyValueTextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class TemperatureMapper extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

  @Override
  public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    if (isValueValid(value.toString())) {
      Text key2 = new Text(getStateFromValue(value.toString()));
      IntWritable value2 = new IntWritable(getTemperatureFrom(value.toString()));
      context.write(key2, value2);
    }
  }

  private boolean isValueValid(final String value) {
    // We expect that the value is a String in the form of : State, Temperature. E.g. MP,77
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\S\\S\\,\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
    return m.matches();
  }

  private String getStateFromValue(final String value) {
    final String[] subvalues = value.split("\\,");
    return subvalues[0];
  }

  private int getTemperatureFrom(final String value) {
    final String[] subvalues = value.split("\\,");
    return Integer.parseInt(subvalues[1]);
  }
}

    public class TemperatureReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

  @Override
  protected void reduce(final Text key, final Iterable<IntWritable> values, final Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int sumOfTemperatures = 0;
    int nbValues = 0;
    int average=0;
    for (IntWritable temperature : values) {
      sumOfTemperatures += temperature.get();
      nbValues++;
    }
    average = sumOfTemperatures / nbValues;
    context.write(key, new IntWritable(average));
  }
}
public class average {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
    /*if (otherArgs.length != 2) {
      System.err.println("Usage: Main <in> <out>");
      System.exit(-1);
    }*/
    Job job = new Job(conf, "Calculate average Temperature");
    job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[2]));

    job.setJarByClass(average.class);

    job.setMapperClass(TemperatureMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(TemperatureReducer.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : -1);
  }

}
```

The code works fine for the input:

```
Ujjain  MP,77
Bhopal  MP,76
Indore  MP,72
Raipur  CG,72
Durg    CG,75
Raigarth        CG,70
Kendujhar   OR,69
Bhubaneswar OR,71
Puri    OR,76
```

But not for some random input like:

```
hello  VI,6
bye RE,2
```

It rather produces an empty output file.

Comment: Could you share output of "value.toString()" before if condition in your map method ? Or else do you see that jobtracker shows your map has received 2 records as an input ?

Answer (score 0):

modify your regular expression for the following to support that kind of input

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]*\\s*[a-zA-Z]{2},\\d+$");
```

Also, you will need split again to get the state

```
String[] subvalues = value.split("\\,")[0].split(" ");
return subvalues[subvalues.length - 1];
```

I hope it helps. In my side, I had to change the key type in the value LongWritable, I am not sure why is not complaining in our side, probably a different api version

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
```